# updating date in mysql (phpMyAdmin)

Tags: mysql, date, phpmyadmin, updates

i have created a table called vendor and imported the document with these commands:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vendor;
CREATE TABLE VENDOR (
V_CODE int,
V_NAME varchar(15),
V_CONTACT varchar(50),
V_AREACODE varchar(3),
V_PHONE varchar(8),
V_STATE varchar(2),
V_ORDER varchar(1)
);
INSERT INTO VENDOR VALUES('21225','Bryson, Inc.','Smithson','615','223-3234','TN','Y');
INSERT INTO VENDOR VALUES('21226','SuperLoo, Inc.','Flushing','904','215-8995','FL','N');
INSERT INTO VENDOR VALUES('21231','D&E Supply','Singh','615','228-3245','TN','Y');
INSERT INTO VENDOR VALUES('21344','Gomez Bros.','Ortega','615','889-2546','KY','N');
INSERT INTO VENDOR VALUES('22567','Dome Supply','Smith','901','678-1419','GA','N');
INSERT INTO VENDOR VALUES('23119','Randsets Ltd.','Anderson','901','678-3998','GA','Y');
INSERT INTO VENDOR VALUES('24004','Brackman Bros.','Browning','615','228-1410','TN','N');
INSERT INTO VENDOR VALUES('24288','ORDVA, Inc.','Hakford','615','898-1234','TN','Y');
INSERT INTO VENDOR VALUES('25443','B&K, Inc.','Smith','904','227-0093',null ,'N');
INSERT INTO VENDOR VALUES('25501','Damal Supplies','Smythe','615','890-3529','TN','N');
INSERT INTO VENDOR VALUES('25595','Rubicon Systems','Orton','904','456-0092','FL','Y');


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product;
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
P_CODE varchar(10),
P_DESCRIPT varchar(35),
P_INDATE datetime,
P_QOH int,
P_MIN int,
P_PRICE float(8),
P_DISCOUNT float(8),
V_CODE int
);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES('11QER/31','Power painter, 15 psi., 3-nozzle','11/3/2007','8','5','109.98999786377','0','25595');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES('13-Q2/P2','7.25-in. pwr. saw blade','12/13/2007','32','15','14.9899997711182','0.05','21344');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES('14-Q1/L3','9.00-in. pwr. saw blade','11/13/2007','18','12','17.4899997711182','0','21344');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES('1546-QQ2','Hrd. cloth, 1/4-in., 2x50','1/15/2008','15','8','39.9500007629395','0','23119');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES('1558-QW1','Hrd. cloth, 1/2-in., 3x50','1/15/2008','23','5','43.9900016784668','0','23119');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES('2232/QTY','B&D jigsaw, 12-in. blade','12/30/2007','8','5','109.919998168945','0.05','24288');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES('2232/QWE','B&D jigsaw, 8-in. blade','12/24/2007','6','5','99.870002746582','0.05','24288');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES('2238/QPD','B&D cordless drill, 1/2-in.','1/20/2008','12','5','38.9500007629395','0.05','25595');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES('23109-HB','Claw hammer','1/20/2008','23','10','9.94999980926514','0.1','21225');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES('23114-AA','Sledge hammer, 12 lb.','1/2/2008','8','5','14.3999996185303','0.05','');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES('54778-2T','Rat-tail file, 1/8-in. fine','12/15/2007','43','20','4.98999977111816','0','21344');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES('89-WRE-Q','Hicut chain saw, 16 in.','2/7/2008','11','5','256.989990234375','0.05','24288');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES('PVC23DRT','PVC pipe, 3.5-in., 8-ft','2/20/2008','188','75','5.86999988555908','0','');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES('SM-18277','1.25-in. metal screw, 25','3/1/2008','172','75','6.98999977111816','0','21225');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES('SW-23116','2.5-in. wd. screw, 50','2/24/2008','237','100','8.44999980926514','0','21231');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES('WR3/TT3','Steel matting, 4''x8''x1/6", .5" mesh','1/17/2008','18','5','119.949996948242','0.1','25595');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CUSTOMER;
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CUS_CODE int,
CUS_LNAME varchar(15),
CUS_FNAME varchar(15),
CUS_INITIAL varchar(1),
CUS_AREACODE varchar(3),
CUS_PHONE varchar(8),
CUS_BALANCE float(8)
);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10010','Ramas','Alfred','A','615','844-2573','0');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10011','Dunne','Leona','K','713','894-1238','0');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10012','Smith','Kathy','W','615','894-2285','345.859985351562');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10013','Olowski','Paul','F','615','894-2180','536.75');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10014','Orlando','Myron','','615','222-1672','0');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10015','O''Brian','Amy','B','713','442-3381','0');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10016','Brown','James','G','615','297-1228','221.190002441406');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10017','Williams','George','','615','290-2556','768.929992675781');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10018','Farriss','Anne','G','713','382-7185','216.550003051758');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10019','Smith','Olette','K','615','297-3809','0');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS invoice;
CREATE TABLE INVOICE (
INV_NUMBER int,
CUS_CODE int,
INV_DATE datetime,
INV_SUBTOTAL float(8),
INV_TAX float(8),
INV_TOTAL float(8)
);
INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES('1001','10014','1/16/2008','24.8999996185303','1.99000000953674','26.8899993896484');
INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES('1002','10011','1/16/2008','9.97999954223633','0.800000011920929','10.7799997329712');
INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES('1003','10012','1/16/2008','153.850006103516','12.3100004196167','166.160003662109');
INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES('1004','10011','1/17/2008','34.9700012207031','2.79999995231628','37.7700004577637');
INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES('1005','10018','1/17/2008','70.4400024414062','5.6399998664856','76.0800018310547');
INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES('1006','10014','1/17/2008','397.829986572266','31.8299999237061','429.660003662109');
INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES('1007','10015','1/17/2008','34.9700012207031','2.79999995231628','37.7700004577637');
INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES('1008','10011','1/17/2008','399.149993896484','31.9300003051758','431.079986572266');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS line;
CREATE TABLE LINE (
INV_NUMBER int,
LINE_NUMBER int,
P_CODE varchar(10),
LINE_UNITS float(8),
LINE_PRICE float(8),
LINE_TOTAL float(8)
);
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES('1001','1','13-Q2/P2','1','14.9899997711182','14.9899997711182');
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES('1001','2','23109-HB','1','9.94999980926514','9.94999980926514');
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES('1002','1','54778-2T','2','4.98999977111816','9.97999954223633');
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES('1003','1','2238/QPD','1','38.9500007629395','38.9500007629395');
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES('1003','2','1546-QQ2','1','39.9500007629395','39.9500007629395');
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES('1003','3','13-Q2/P2','5','14.9899997711182','74.9499969482422');
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES('1004','1','54778-2T','3','4.98999977111816','14.9700002670288');
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES('1004','2','23109-HB','2','9.94999980926514','19.8999996185303');
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES('1005','1','PVC23DRT','12','5.86999988555908','70.4400024414062');
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES('1006','1','SM-18277','3','6.98999977111816','20.9699993133545');
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES('1006','2','2232/QTY','1','109.919998168945','109.919998168945');
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES('1006','3','23109-HB','1','9.94999980926514','9.94999980926514');
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES('1006','4','89-WRE-Q','1','256.989990234375','256.989990234375');
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES('1007','1','13-Q2/P2','2','14.9899997711182','29.9799995422363');
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES('1007','2','54778-2T','1','4.98999977111816','4.98999977111816');
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES('1008','1','PVC23DRT','5','5.86999988555908','29.3500003814697');
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES('1008','2','WR3/TT3','3','119.949996948242','359.850006103516');
INSERT INTO LINE VALUES('1008','3','23109-HB','1','9.94999980926514','9.94999980926514');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS EMP;
CREATE TABLE EMP (
EMP_NUM int,
EMP_TITLE varchar(4),
EMP_LNAME varchar(15),
EMP_FNAME varchar(15),
EMP_INITIAL varchar(1),
EMP_DOB datetime,
EMP_HIRE_DATE datetime,
EMP_AREACODE varchar(3),
EMP_PHONE varchar(8),
EMP_MGR int
);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('100','Mr.','Kolmycz','George','D','6/15/1942','3/15/1985','615','324-5456','');
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('101','Ms.','Lewis','Rhonda','G','3/19/1965','4/25/1986','615','324-4472','100');
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('102','Mr.','VanDam','Rhett','','11/14/1958','12/20/1990','901','675-8993','100');
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('103','Ms.','Jones','Anne','M','10/16/1974','8/28/1994','615','898-3456','100');
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('104','Mr.','Lange','John','P','11/8/1971','10/20/1994','901','504-4430','105');
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('105','Mr.','Williams','Robert','D','3/14/1975','11/8/1998','615','890-3220','');
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('106','Mrs.','Smith','Jeanine','K','2/12/1968','1/5/1989','615','324-7883','105');
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('107','Mr.','Diante','Jorge','D','8/21/1974','7/2/1994','615','890-4567','105');
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('108','Mr.','Wiesenbach','Paul','R','2/14/1966','11/18/1992','615','897-4358','');
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('109','Mr.','Smith','George','K','6/18/1961','4/14/1989','901','504-3339','108');
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('110','Mrs.','Genkazi','Leighla','W','5/19/1970','12/1/1990','901','569-0093','108');
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('111','Mr.','Washington','Rupert','E','1/3/1966','6/21/1993','615','890-4925','105');
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('112','Mr.','Johnson','Edward','E','5/14/1961','12/1/1983','615','898-4387','100');
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('113','Ms.','Smythe','Melanie','P','9/15/1970','5/11/1999','615','324-9006','105');
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('114','Ms.','Brandon','Marie','G','11/2/1956','11/15/1979','901','882-0845','108');
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('115','Mrs.','Saranda','Hermine','R','7/25/1972','4/23/1993','615','324-5505','105');
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('116','Mr.','Smith','George','A','11/8/1965','12/10/1988','615','890-2984','108');
```

but when I entered commands:
SELECT INV_DATE FROM invoice;
the data only shows 0000-00-00 00:00:00

how do i update the whole column in INV_DATE to what I wish (example 1/16/2008)?

```
INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES('1001','10014','1/16/2008','24.8999996185303','1.99000000953674','26.8899993896484');
INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES('1002','10011','1/16/2008','9.97999954223633','0.800000011920929','10.7799997329712');
INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES('1003','10012','1/16/2008','153.850006103516','12.3100004196167','166.160003662109');
INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES('1004','10011','1/17/2008','34.9700012207031','2.79999995231628','37.7700004577637');
INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES('1005','10018','1/17/2008','70.4400024414062','5.6399998664856','76.0800018310547');
INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES('1006','10014','1/17/2008','397.829986572266','31.8299999237061','429.660003662109');
INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES('1007','10015','1/17/2008','34.9700012207031','2.79999995231628','37.7700004577637');
INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES('1008','10011','1/17/2008','399.149993896484','31.9300003051758','431.079986572266');
```

Comment: The format for `DATETIME` is yyyy-mm-dd [hh:mm:ss] eg 2008-01-17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type of INV_DATE in invoice table is 'datetime'. The default format of datetime is 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'.

So, if you insert values in different format, it will misinterpret it and show unexpected output.

Update the type of the INV_DATE column to any other favorable one or insert date and time formatted in this format :  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS[.fraction]

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you Jameel! :-) i was wondering what the default format was. i will just change the format of the date from m/dd/yyyy to YYY-MM-DD